# How to inherit CSS property from grand parents

Tags: html, css, frontend

Is there any way I can inherit CSS property such as background color from the grand parent of the element, like I have a `<div>` tag inside the `<main>` tag which is inside the `<body>` tag, I want to inherit background color property form the `<body>` tag bypassing the `<main>` tag background-color property. How can I achieve this using CSS only?

Comment: The answer is no; you can't inherit properties from an ancestor that isn't the parent. (Unless the property is inherited all the way down the tree, which by the sounds of it, isn't what you want)

Comment: No I am not inheriting all the way down As I mentioned I have used different background color for body and different for main tag and I want to inherit the background color of body tag, But It's looking like it's not possible as you said

Comment: The current answer by @arlot sums up the recommended implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple classes can be added  to the grandchild and grandparent.

```
<div class="A B">
  <div class="C">
    <div class="B D">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="A C">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inherit css keyword. Here is an example

```
<body style="background-color: burlywood;">
<main style="background-color: inherit;">   
  <div style="background-color: inherit;">
  </div>
</main>
```